# How to improve the code for dynamically allocated strings in C?

Tags: c, char, malloc

So I'm practicing and learning C right now and came across a rather easy challenge from CodeWars that asked to print out a string of "Aa~", "Pa!", and "Aa!" depending on whether n was <= 6 or not. I know how we can do this with arrays but wanted to try out using dynamically allocated char arrays like with malloc for efficiency sake.

I want to make sure I get the basics down with these questions

1. So I know in other malloc examples with int we set up a pointer (of type int) to point to an allocated memory block. Is it still a pointer when I declare "char *ptr" to point to an allocated memory block because pardon me I thought "char *anything" meant it was a convention to represent a string. So not sure why the below is working somewhat if I'm not setting up a pointer like "char **ptr" as I thought.
2. why do I get a "malloc: *** error for object 0x100000fab: pointer being freed was not allocated" type of error when I try to return the answer especially when the "val" is 1 or 0? I read somewhere that changing the pointer(string?), answer, to NULL will solve the issue but not entirely sure why this works.

3 To continue in general with the above question, for freeing up space, what is the best method to do so if we dynamically allocate a memory block in a function but need to return a value from that function? As in, do we free up the space after or before?

Thank you all for your input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define val 1
char *sc(int); // function declaration/prototype 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *answer = sc(val);
    printf("The answer is %s\n", answer);
    answer = NULL; // why does this work
    free(answer);
    return 0;
}

char *sc(int n) {
  // if n < 6 then will have an extra "Aa!" after "Pa!" at the nth position
    char *ptr = (char*) malloc(n*4);
    if (ptr == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed");
    }
    char *first = "Aa~ ";
    char *second = "Pa! Aa!";
    char *third = "Pa!";
    if (n <= 6 && n >1) {
        for (int i = 0; i <n-1; i++){
            ptr = strcat(ptr, first);
        }
        ptr = strcat(ptr, second);
        }
    else if (n> 6){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            ptr = strcat(ptr, first);
        }
        ptr = strcat(ptr, third);
    }
    else if (n <= 1){
        ptr = "";
    }
    else {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(0);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: `answer = NULL; // why does this work` -- It doesn't.  It may appear to work, but the line just after it won't do anything, because your pointer doesn't point to the original memory anymore.  Very likely you've got a memory leak there.

Comment: Given `char *ptr = (char*) malloc(n*4);`, `ptr = ""` is both a memory leak and a likely source of memory corruption when the caller of this function calls `free()` on the pointer it returns.

Comment: `strcat(ptr, first);` is causing undefined behavior. `strcat()` requires the arguments to be null-terminated strings, but you never initialized the memory that `ptr` points to after allocating it.

Comment: `ptr = strcat(ptr, second);` looks like a buffer overrun to me.

Comment: If you don't use `argc` and `argv`, don't declare them.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you have with your code is that you're not zeroing out the buffer you get from `malloc()`, so the first `strcat()` is not necessarily going to write at the start of the string but at the end.

You can fix that with a `strcpy()` right after the `malloc()` call and check:

```
strcpy(ptr, "");
```

Or, equivalently, you can just set the first byte of the buffer to zero. Since C strings are zero-terminated strings, setting a character to zero will indicate it's at the end:

```
ptr[0] = 0;
```

You also seem to be allocating your buffer too short. If you write `n-1` copies of `Aa~` (4 bytes) plus one copy of `Pa! Aa!` (8 bytes when you include the terminating zero!) you'll actually need `4 * (n+1)` as space. So either always allocate that or do so in case `n < 6` which is where you need the additional bytes.

This is also a problem:

```
ptr = "";
```

Because now your `ptr` is no longer pointing to a buffer returned by `malloc()`, but to a static (empty) string in your binary. It's quite probable that this is the place where you're getting the trouble from `free()`, since calling it on a static string in your binary is definitely wrong.

Furthermore, after you set `ptr = ""` you no longer have any reference to the buffer you allocated, which means you most likely just created a memory leak!

In that case, you should simply use `strcpy()` or set the first byte to zero. But if you do that at the start of the program, you don't need to do it here.

Finally, `free(NULL);` works (as in, doesn't throw an error) because that's part of its specification, you can pass it a NULL pointer and it will do nothing. But note that it's not freeing the buffer you allocated, so you have a memory leak here too.

I'd further refactor the second part of your code so you don't have too much repetition appending the strings:

```
char *sc(int n) {
    /* if n <= 6 then will have an extra "Aa!"
     * after "Pa!" at the nth position.
     */
    char *ptr;
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Error!");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr = (char*) malloc(4 * (n+1));
    if (ptr == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(ptr, "");
    if (n > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            strcat(ptr, "Aa~ ");
        }
        strcat(ptr, "Pa!");
        if (n <= 6) {
            strcat(ptr, " Ah!");
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Also note you don't need to assign the result of `strcat()` back to `ptr` every time, since it always returns its first argument anyways, so assigning it there isn't changing anything really.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I thought "char *anything" meant it was a convention to represent a string. So not sure why the below is working somewhat if I'm not setting up a pointer like "char **ptr" as I thought.

You're allocating memory for a string, so it just needs to be `char *`. `char **` would be used for an array of multiple strings, or for a pointer to a variable that contains a pointer to a string.

> 2. why do I get a "malloc: *** error for object 0x100000fab: pointer being freed was not allocated"

You get that when you do `ptr = "";`. After you do this, `ptr` no longer points to the memory that was allocated with `malloc`, it points to that string literal. If you want to set the allocated memory to an empty string, you can do

```
ptr[0] = '\0';
```

This puts a null terminator in the first element of the string.

You also need to do that before the code that uses `strcat()` to append to the string. Otherwise you're appending to uninitialized data. Simplest would be to do it immediately after allocating the memory (then you don't need it in the `n <= 1` block.

The `else` block is not needed. There are no other possibilities than the 3 you test for unless the CPU is malfunctioning (in which case all bets are off). However, you should check for `n < 1` before calling `malloc()`, as you can't allocate negative memory, and `malloc(0)` may return `NULL`.

When you allocate space for `ptr`, you need to add 1 byte for the terminating null of the string.

```
char *sc(int n) {
    // if n < 6 then will have an extra "Aa!" after "Pa!" at the nth position
    if (n >= 1) {
        char *ptr = malloc(n*4 + 1);
    } else {
        char *ptr = malloc(1);
    }
    if (ptr == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    ptr[0] = '\0'; // initialize empty string
    char *first = "Aa~ ";
    char *second = "Pa! Aa!";
    char *third = "Pa!";
    if (n <= 6 && n >1) {
        for (int i = 0; i <n-1; i++){
            ptr = strcat(ptr, first);
        }
        ptr = strcat(ptr, second);
        }
    else if (n> 6){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            ptr = strcat(ptr, first);
        }
        ptr = strcat(ptr, third);
    }
    else if (n <= 1){
        // nothing to do
    }

    return ptr;
}
```